# Get user's home folder under Python process started by supervisord

Tags: python, django, freebsd, supervisord

I would like to store login secrets in a file from the current user's account in a Django configuration. I'm using the recommended portable way to get the home folder, as in:

```
os.path.expanduser("~")
```

This worked in all environments, both locally and both when started with `gunicorn -D config.wsgi` on a server.

My problem is however that I introduced supervisord to control the gunicorn process and now this function doesn't work, it simply returns `/`.

This is the relevant section of supervisord.conf

```
[program:kek_django]
command=.../venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi
directory=.../django
user=testuser
```

Under this environmet, os.path.expanduser("~") becomes `/`.

Can you tell me either how to fix this problem either by fixing the environment or the function used to detect the home directory?

note: OS is FreeBSD 10, if that is relevant

update: os.environ reports the following under the running process:

```
'SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL': 'unix:///var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock',
'RC_PID': '84177',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/19.3.0',
'SUPERVISOR_ENABLED': '1', 
'SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME': 'test_django',
'PWD': '/',
'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'config.settings.production', 
'SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME': 'test_django', 
'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin',
'HOME': '/'
```

Comment: First, are you sure both `gunicorn` and `supervisord` are actually running as `testuser`, and that `testuser` actually has a home directory?

Comment: Second, can you try adding some code at the start that prints out `os.getuid(), os.geteuid(), os.getsuid()` (or just `os.getresuid()` if you're on 3.2+), and then, for each of the three, prints `pwd.getpwuid(i)`? Ideally both with and without `supervisord`?

Comment: The reason I ask is that, unless the `HOME` environment variable is set, `expanduser` just looks up your user ID with `getpwuid` and uses its `pw_dir` value. If `supervisord` is, say, setting your effective ID to `testuser` but your real ID to `nobody`, it'll end up looking for `nobody`'s home directory, which won't do you any good.

Comment: os.getuid() == os.geteuid() == 1001 == the good user id. `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir` actually works!
getsuid and getresuid are not available for me (2.7).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why `HOME` is broken, but at least we have a workaround now…

Comment: I just finished editing that into my answer, along with a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `supervisord`'s docs for [Subprocess Environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment) say:

> No shell is executed by `supervisord` when it runs a subprocess, so environment variables such as `USER`, `PATH`, `HOME`, `SHELL`, `LOGNAME`, etc. are not changed from their defaults or otherwise reassigned. This is particularly important to note when you are running a program from a `supervisord` run as root with a `user=` stanza in the configuration. Unlike `cron`, `supervisord` does not attempt to divine and override “fundamental” environment variables like `USER`, `PATH`, `HOME`, and `LOGNAME` when it performs a `setuid` to the user defined within the `user=` program config option. If you need to set environment variables for a particular program that might otherwise be set by a shell invocation for a particular user, you must do it explicitly within the `environment=` program config option. An example of setting these enviroment variables is as below.

```
[program:apache2]
command=/home/chrism/bin/httpd -c "ErrorLog /dev/stdout" -DFOREGROUND
user=chrism
environment=HOME="/home/chrism",USER="chrism"
```

So, that's the actual fix. (If you construct the `supervisord.conf` file dynamically and need to know how to look those values up dynamically, I can explain that, but it's pretty easy, and I don't think you need it anyway.)

```
[program:kek_django]
command=.../venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi
directory=.../django
user=testuser
environment=HOME="/home/testuser"
```

If this doesn't make sense to you, consider:

If you're running `supervisord` as root, it doesn't have `testuser`'s `HOME` or anything else. And all it does is `setuid(testuser)`, which just changes its user ID; it doesn't give the shell, or any other part of the system, any opportunity to set up the variables for `testuser`. Most similar tools have workarounds to fake it, following in the well-worn footsteps of how `cron` works, but `supervisord` intentionally chose not to do that.

---

Alternatively, as the docs for [`expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) say:

> On Unix, an initial `~` is replaced by the environment variable HOME if it is set; otherwise the current user’s home directory is looked up in the password directory through the built-in module pwd. An initial `~user` is looked up directly in the password directory.

And a quick look at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/posixpath.py#l251) shows that it does this in the most obvious way possible.

So there are three obvious workarounds from within your code:

1. Use `~testuser` instead of `~` (and you can even generate that programmatically from the username if you want).
2. Write your own `expanduser` function that just does the `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir` without checking for `HOME`.
3. Manually set `HOME` to `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir` at startup if it's `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In my case I'll just use `home_folder = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir` as `HOME` wasn't used for anything else. Nice to know what is the exact reason behind the behaviour though!